# Rails views: missing template after render called following failed validation with nested resources

Tags: validation, rest, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, render

I'm trying to work with failed validations in Rails 3.

I have a chapters resource, with nested comments.  There is only one view in total; the show view from the chapters_controller,  which contains a form to post a new comment and points to the comments_controller create action as follows (controller code is included):

http://pastie.org/1338126

when it fails validation,  it incorrectly routes to: '/chapters/1/comments' and displays the following on the page:

```
Template is missing

Missing template http://localhost:3000/chapters/1 with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb, :rjs]} in view paths "/app/views", "", "/"
```

cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1):

For those in the future, I just had a similar problem.

I was trying to render when validation failed for the address create action:

```
render new_user_address_path(@user)
#Normally this should work with a redirect_to or a link_to but render doesn't work this way
```

instead you should:

```
render 'new'
```

As @ideaasylum mentioned, You can't *render* a "named helper" but you *can* render an action. To me, it seems like an idiosyncrasy with rails. Technically a named path and the action should go to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the render call:

```
if @comment.save
  redirect_to chapter_url(params[:chapter_id])
else
  render chapter_url(params[:chapter_id])
end
```

I don't think it's correct to pass a URL to render (see the api here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render). Typically you call

```
render :action => new
```

which will render the new view of the current controller. Since you want to render the chapter 'show' view (i.e., a different controller's view), I think the call should be more like:

```
render :template => 'chapters/show'
```

My Rails knowledge is getting a bit rusty and things could have changed with Rails 3. Hope that helps anyway...

Comment: Thanks Jamie, Unfortunately,  it's still redirecting to 'chapters/1/comments'

I'm a bit stumped ...

Answer (score 0):

After you redirect, you must return immediately since redirect_to does not return.

```
 if @comment.save
      redirect_to chapter_url(params[:chapter_id]) and return
    else
      render chapter_url(params[:chapter_id]) and return
    end
```